# factoring of $ e^{2x}-3e^{x}+2 = 0 $

Tags: factoring

How does

$ e^{2x}-3e^{x}+2 = 0 $

factors to

$ (e^x - 1) (e^x - 2 )  $

---

Because when I try to factor:

$ e^{2x}-3e^{x}+2 = 0 $

$ e^{2x}-2e^{x}-1e^{x}+2 = 0 $

But $-2e^{x} * -1e^{x}$ should give 2 e^x^2 instead of $2e^{2x}$

Comment: Well, $-2-1=-3$ isn't $-2\cdot(-1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistakenly think that

$$e^x \cdot e^x=e^{x^2}$$

But $e^a \cdot e^b =e^{a+b}$. Your confusion comes most likely from confusing 
$\left( e^x \right)^2$ which is actually $e^{2x}$ with $e^{x^2}$. Anyhow

$$\left( e^x \right)^2 \neq e^{x^2}$$

Comment: yes you are correct. this is what i was missing.

Comment: @shunya At least as crucially, you were missing that $-2e^x-1e^x\ne(-2e^x)(-1e^x)$.

Answer (score 3):

put $t=e^{x}$. You get

$$t^2 -3t + 2$$

Factor this one (by finding its roots,for example), and substitute back $t=e^{x}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

use $t=e^x$ and note that for the second degree trinomial that come from we have $1 \cdot 2=2$ and $-(1+2)=-3$.